# What was the first Unix platform to have the 'yes' command?

Tags: command, history

I have just answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37701967/5255018) question on SO, and it fired off my curiosity a little. So I've searched around but can't find an answer ('yes' is a difficult thing to search for!)

There are related questions about what `yes` does, but I can't find any about its history, and I'm curious what is the first instance of? is there any documentation for it...

Comment: Let's start a search for the 'yes' creator and have him run for president!

Comment: It appeared in 2.9BSD, file-timestamp July 10, 1981, no attribution.  The CSRG disk also has it with an earlier timestamp for 4.1 (October 8, 1980).  Aside from manpage, no documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest version in the [Unix history repository](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo) is credited to Ken Thompson in V7, on [January 10, 1979](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/4c37048d6dd7b8f65481c8c86ef8cede2e782bb3).

The [4BSD](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4/usr/src/cmd/yes.c) version only adds the CSRG's SCCS header, dated October 8, 1980.

In the repository, the V7 version doesn't have a manpage; that appears in [4BSD](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/9cf6bd1eabeac41cf34f00ec9b9475c18fce69cd).

Comment: I do love the manpage! Thank you for the effort, I've no idea why I enjoy that being documented as much as I do.